# extract value from projection query in objectify

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, projection, objectify

I have an account entity and I need to get the user name from the Datastore.

```
String username = ofy().load().type(Account.class).filterKey("in", userId).project("username");
```

My code is not working. I keep getting `Query<Account>`. How do I complete it?

Answer (score 3):

You are missing the methods `first()` and `now()` as in

```
String username = ofy().load().type(Account.class).
filterKey("in", userId).project("username").first().now().getUsername();
```